# Compiling structure of .as back in swf

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, compilation

I am having a problem related to flash/as3 files.,

I decompiled an .swf file (shop in a open source game) wich, its in chinese. i want to translate some chinese pushstrings in "text" to english text.

I can decompile it simply, as wells after decompiling, editing it.

My main problem is (after spending 3 days in the Internet searching a method 2 do it), i can't just publish a new version of the .swf , with the .as translates back. It just gives an 1kb swf with no .as on it.

Btw: the .swf files consists of no animations, since its a sub part of a main one.

The structure of .swf after decompiling looks like this:

[tinypic.com(safe) - .swf structure](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2ldzy4o&s=8#.U6UVI_ldWSo)

I'm using Flash builder + Flash CS6 to edit. -- in case link broken -- http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2ldzy4o&s=8#.U6UVI_ldWSo

Any help would be apreciated. Thank you community ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De-compiling a Flash (SWF) file in order to recompile it will very, very rarely work.

It could be as simple as you having one error, but you'll find that all variable names are using standard names and without knowing the structure of the application, it wouldn't be easy to work out where the problems are.

You should begin by making sure that CS6 has the correct document class set up. Once you've got that, you'll start seeing the errors. With that amount of classes, though, I would expect there to be a **lot** of errors.

Comment: I've searched the Internet for about 5 days or something to make a method work, like u said barely worked. My main interest was to convert .as3 with Traditional Chinese Lang, to English. I found a program with a little slow method: JPEXS Free Flash Decompiler.

I can open a .swf file and edit it without decompiling, and edit the   text(hard work with /Google translator) but, hey, it works (don't know how but somehow he compiles the traits of the text in the .as3).  And I had to be cautious editing it, one little error or a " missing bugged the whole file.

Thanks anyway for your response :)

Answer (score 0):

I've searched the Internet for about 5 days or something to make a method work, like u said barely worked. My main interest was to convert .as3 with Traditional Chinese Lang, to English. I found a program with a little slow method: JPEXS Free Flash Decompiler.

I can open a .swf file and edit it without decompiling, and edit the   text(hard work with /Google translator) but, hey, it works (don't know how but somehow he compiles the traits of the text in the .as3).  And I had to be cautious editing it, one little error or a " missing bugged the whole file.

Thanks anyway for your response :)